# Reference to member 'name' cannot be resolved without a contextual type in my array of objects

Tags: swift, function, uisearchbar

> 'compendium' is an array of objects called 'Monster' which has the attribute 'name'.
> I'm trying to create a search bar for my tableView that searches through all the different names of the monsters. I'm unsure of why I'm getting this error and can't quite find an answer.

```
var compendium = [Monster]()
var index = 0;
var filteredData:[String]!

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
    
    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? compendium[index].name : compendium[index].name.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in

        return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}//end search bar


Monster: Codable{
    let ID: Int
    let name: String
    let region: String
    let classification: String
    let description: String
    let imageName: String
    
    init(ID: Int, name: String, region: String, classification: String,
         description: String, imageName: String){
        self.ID =  ID;                  self.name = name;
        self.region = region;           self.classification = classification;
        self.description = description; self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems strange.  Are you sure that `filteredData` isnt' supposed to be an array of `Monster`? I guess that `compendium` is the "full array of Monster", no? If so, I guess you want: `filteredData = searchTex.isEmpty ? compendium : compendium.filter { (aMonter: Monster) {return aMonster.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil  }}` But to clarify, show what's `compendium` and what's `Monster`.

Comment: name here [index].name is an array ?

Comment: I updated the post to make it clearer. [index].name is a String constant within the array of type Monster.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?